# How to automatically render text with new font size when prefererd font size is changed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want the font size of a textview to change automatically when the user changes their preferred font size on their device.

I set up the observer like so but I need to reload the page to see the font size change.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                          selector:@selector(preferredFontChanged:)
                                              name:UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification
                                            object:nil];


- (void)preferredFontChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
 [self setupCustomUIView];
}

- (void)setupCustomUIView
{
 [self.bodyTextView setLineHeightScale:0.5f];
 [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check and ensure that the line where you set font is executed after `UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification` notification.

For example, you can simply try below.. (Refer this tutorial [here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2013/12/17/supporting-dynamic-type.html))

```
- (void)setupCustomUIView
{
    // Assuming that bodyTextView is actually your dynamic text sized view.
    self.bodyTextView.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline1];
}
```